# Add a drop down in a table using HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to add a drop down box in a table as a part of registration form. 
Here is my code below :-

```
<html>
<body></body>
<h1>Cab</h1>
<TABLE BORDER="0">
    <TR>
        <TD>Name</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="left"><INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="25" NAME="fname">
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Phone Number</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="left"><INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="25" NAME="phnnum">
        </TD>
    </TR>
            <TR>
        <TD class = "select">Online Password (Repeated) 
        <select>        
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <TD ALIGN="center"></TD>
        </TD>   
    </TR>
</TABLE>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear">
</html>
```

When I do this the drop down box doesn't come in a format as the other fields come. 
I want the drop down box right below the Text Field above it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the Drop Down box doesnt come in a format as the other fields come"

Comment: You might want to close the `<body>`  tag...

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3yCZL/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its because you have put "Online Password (Repeated)" text and drop down in a same column **td**

and the second **TD** is blank..

```
<TR>
    <TD class = "select">Online Password (Repeated) 
    <select>        
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <TD ALIGN="center"></TD>
    </TD>   
</TR>
```

replace above code with below

```
<TR>
    <TD class = "select">Online Password (Repeated)         
    </TD>   
    <TD ALIGN="center">
       <select>        
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       </select>
    </TD>        
</TR>
```

I hope u can now find where u made mistake

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FyCA/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Cab</h1>
    <TABLE BORDER="0">
      <TR>
        <TD>Name</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="left">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="25" NAME="fname">
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Phone Number</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="left">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="25" NAME="phnnum">
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Online Password (Repeated)</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="left">
          <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit">
    <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this I was able to have a drop down list and no label on the box since I am using a table and the name appears above the list box

```
<TD class = "select" ALIGN="center">
  <select name="gname">        
        <option value="Free to Play">Free to Play</option>
        <option value="Premium">Premium</option>
        <option value="VIP">VIP</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: your code has some errors TD should be lower letters...