# creating a table in html using javascript and crm data

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, crm

In my javascript file, I'm trying to create a table using html.

I have list of records of an entity which has fields like contractid, name, address etc.

```
var filter = "?$select=*&$filter=_plus_franchisee_value eq " + serviceProviderID;
PlusCRM.RetrieveMultiple("plus_franchiseecontracts", filter, function (records) {
        $("#tblNewAssignments").find("tbody").empty();
        console.log("vendorcontracts list....................");
        console.log(records);
        });
```

In the first column of table I want to show the dropdown which should show all the contract id's. Once I select the id, the 2nd and 3rd column should populate its respective name and address.
Once its filled, 2nd row should appear and dropdown should show again the list of accounts.

html:

```
<body onfocusout="parent.setEmailRange();" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5>New Assignments</h5>
            <hr>
            <div id="divNewAssignments">
                <table id="tblNewAssignments">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Vendor Contract</th> (this should be drop down)
                            <th>Volume Purchased</th>
                            <th>% Fulfilled</th> 
                            <th>Volume Owed</th> 
                            <th>Vendor Amount</th> 

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    <tfoot></tfoot>
                </table>
                <div class="inline-loader"></div>
                <div class="no-records" style="display: none">No records found</div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help you i am not sure.
[add-a-drop-down-in-a-table-using-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018842/add-a-drop-down-in-a-table-using-html)

and if you want to do above same thing with javascript you can do like this.

```
function func(){
var addrow = '<tr>'
addrow += <td>'
addrow += '<select>        
            <option value="">record1</option>
            <option value="">record2</option>
            <option value="">record3</option>
            <option value="">record4</option>
    </select>'
addrow += '</td>'
addrow += '</tr>'

for(var i = 0; i < length_of_records; i++){
   jQuery("#tblNewAssignments tbody").append(addrow);
   }
}
```

Comment: but how to build option value sets? the list is dynamic here.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question ?

Comment: here <select>        
            <option value="">record1</option>
            <option value="">record2</option>
            <option value="">record3</option>
            <option value="">record4</option>
    </select>' you are adding manually right?.  i have a dynamic list with differernt number of records each time, and i want to show all those list values in a dropdown. How to add those list items to the dropdown

Comment: addoption = '<option>' \n addoption += '</option>' \n for(var i = 0; i < length_of_records; i++){
   jQuery("#tblNewAssignments tbody tr td select").append(addoption);
   }
} This will help you to dynamically create option according your records, and

Comment: This will help you to add values in options table = jQuery("#tblNewAssignments tbody tr td select");
                        for(var i = 1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
                            for(var j = 1; j<table.rows[i].cells.length; j++){
                                table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = values;
                            }
                        } something like that will help you to add items in dropdown

Comment: thanks I will try, also how to write a click event for that dropdown values. Once the item is selected from dropdown i want to populate selected records data to other columns

Comment: I'm doing like this: var select = document.createElement("select");
                for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = records[i]["plus_franchiseecontractid"];
                    option.text = records[i]["plus_name"];
                    select.add(option);
                }

Comment: but when adding to html :strHtml += '    <td>' + select  + '</td>'; it shows [object htmlselectelement] instead of dropdown

Comment: you need to add option to only select element will not help you